# Most efficient parallel computing package in Python for hierarchy spawning multiple processes at each level

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing

I'm not sure if this is the correct place to post this question, so please let me know if this would better be posted somewhere else.

I have some data processing that I'd like to do in parallel in Python to speed things up. A simple hierarchy diagram of the parent directory and sub directories is shown below:

[image]

for `day_1....day_n`, `system_1....system_m`, and `{vehicle_1i....vehicle_pi} for i=1,...,m`.

I am only familiar with using `multiprocessing.pool` on a single node on my computing cluster. Is it possible to create a pool for each day, and then within each day spawn a pool for systems, and then in each system spawn a pool for vehicles etc?

It seems to me that this wouldn't be the most efficient way to do this, so any advice as to what would be better please let me know!

Thanks.